# Website image fragmented in Safari

Tags: macos, website, safari, pictures

When going to [Ubuntu Blog - 10 Desktop Snaps written in June](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/07/07/10-desktop-snaps-written-in-june/?utm_source=Newsletter_July&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Desktop-16.04-LTS&) I get in my safari browser on mac os x a fragmented background image.

Why does this happen and how can this problem be resolved from client or server side?

[image: fragmented background image]

Comment: You can't solve it.  The problem is caused by a coding error that only surfaces with Safari

Comment: @Ramhound Well, this is also an answer. If you could give me more details which prove this is a coding error in safari I can award you the answer.

Comment: I am not going to analyze the source code, find the coding error, and submit an answer.  Report the problem to the person responsible for the website.